# So... the target class does not exist... ok?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to do a simple form, a very simple form.

I'm making my own validating request, but the error message is this:

> Target class [app\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost] does not exist.

The code can't be simpliest as I wrote it, so I can't understand where is the problem.

Did u see any bad?

`EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;


class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view ('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function store(StoreEnviarCurriculumPost $request)
    {
        EnviarCurriculum::create($request->validated());

        return back() -> with('status', 'Curriculum creado con éxito!');
    }
}
```

`StoreEnviarCurriculumPost.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreEnviarCurriculumPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nif' => 'required|min:1|max:20'
        ];
    }
}
```

**============================================================================================================================**

**(I don't think html is necessary, but just in case ...)**

`enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Enviar Currículum</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('partials.errores_de_validacion')
    @include('partials.status_de_la_session')

    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <h4>Datos Personales</h4>    
        <small class="pull-right">sin espacios, ni guiones</small>
        <br>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="nif" id="nif" class="form-control" placeholder="* NIF/NIE/Pasaporte" maxlength="20" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input autocomplete="nope" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="* Nombre" maxlength="50" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="apellido1" id="apellido1" class="form-control" placeholder="* 1º Apellido" maxlength="50" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="apellido2" id="apellido2" class="form-control" placeholder="2º Apellido" maxlength="50" data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <select class="form-control" name="sexo" required id="sexo">
            <option disabled selected value="">* Sexo</option>
            <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
            <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `app` should be `App`. Change this:

```
use app\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;
```

To:

```
use App\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;
```

Comment: Updated my answer. As you can see `app` is in small case. But your namespace is in UC First Case. So change `app` to `App`.

Comment: Oh my god... the snippet plugin puts me automatically with lower case -_- well, it works, thanks so much pal!!!!

Comment: @ElcondeLucanor it is really important that you use a good IDE. I have no idea if VSCode have good extensions for PHP/Laravel, but it is imperative you start using a better IDE as if you are using PHPStorm, it would already have added it correctly without errors, so you can work better.